# Renting a car from private persons in California

Tags: usa, car-rentals, automobiles, california

Is there an online service that connects local residents that are willing to rent out their car to people looking to rent a car?

I'm familiar with such a system in The Netherlands ([SnappCar](https://www.snappcar.nl/)), but was wondering if something similar exists in the US, especially in California.

By renting a car from a private person I hope to lower the costs compared to renting it from a regular company.

Comment: How do you expect the insurance to work? Quite often, that's actually the bulk of the cost...

Comment: The SnappCar system I mentioned in my post took care of that when I used it, they charged a fee for that. But even with insurance, renting a vehicle through them was 75% cheaper than using a regular company.

Comment: @BartArondson 75% cheaper, as in the cost was 1/4 of what you would have paid for a normal rental?

Comment: Yes, the most recent time at least. I paid €30 for a van for a day. A comparable van would've cost me €110 using a normal rental (ok, that's 72%). Given these questions, I'm starting to get the feeling that this concept is not very widespread though... I guess my chances are slim in finding something similar in the US, but I think the questions fits travel, so I'll leave it here.

Comment: There is FlightCar (https://flightcar.com/), which is not exactly what you're looking for, as you are still renting from the company, but you are renting private cars that people parked there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly rent from private parties their [Relay Rides](http://www.relayrides.com) is the site that allows you to do exactly that.

Insurance is something else entirely.  Normally insurers in the US want to cover the driver long term 6+ months.  I have been in a situation like this looking for a short term insurance for someone and I've not had much luck.  Relay Rides doesn't specify if they provide insurance for the car you're renting from a 3rd party.

Comment: It seems that Relay Rides does provide insurance, if I understand the [article they posted](https://support.relayrides.com/hc/en-us/articles/203990610-I-d-like-a-detailed-explanation-of-insurance-and-protection-provisions) correctly.

Comment: Most likely the case since insurance regulations are per state.